Is there an AssertJ predicate to return the original object under test?
I'm testing that a class returns an instance of the same type modified in some way. After initializing the object I want to make verify that starting state. So for example:
CLS cls = new CLS(a, b, c);
assertThat(cls.property1()).isEqualTo(x);
assertThat(cls.property2()).isEqualTo(y);
assertThat(cls.method(n)).predicates();

I'd like to do this more compactly because there are quite a few variations to test. Something like this:
CLS cls = assertThat(new CLS(a, b, c))
    .extracting("property1", "property2").isEqualTo(x,y).getOriginalObject();
assertThat(cls.method(n)).predicates();

This doesn't work without something like getOriginalObject that returns the original object. Is there anything like this in the AssertJ library?

What a purpose of getOriginalObject in this scenario? You ignoring its result.

Instantiate and verify state in a single line while.

By the way, this doesn't fit in with the common guideline for unit tests to have a "given-when-then" structure: have some lines that set up required values (given); then a blank line followed by actions on the system under test (when); then a blank line followed by assertions (then).

@k314159 I'm not sure what you're seeing that doesn't fit, but specifying spacing is a style guideline. There also isn't one globally accepted definition for the structure of a unit test.

You're mixing the last two parts ("when" and "then") into a single one-liner. I'm not saying that this is one globally accepted guideline, but it is quite common. It's also called "arrange-act-assert".

Version 3.27.0 will add a new .actual() API to access the value under test (see #3489).
However, this won't help in your example as extracting changes the object under test.
To achieve what you have in mind and assuming that CLS has getters, returns might help:
CLS cls = assertThat(new CLS(a, b, c))
  .returns(x, from(CLS::getProperty1))
  .returns(y, from(CLS::getProperty2))
  .actual();

// additional code that uses `cls`

Please note that from is an optional syntax sugar.

ah, ok. Thats helpful. I wasn't aware of either of those. Thanks!

Version 3.27.0 is now available.
